# Laravel eloquent range

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I wanted to retrieve the latest 100 user emails so I used the following:

```
$user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->take(100);
```

How would I go about selecting the **next** 100 emails? Is there a range operator I could use? 
For example `->take(100,200)` (take latest emails from 100-200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Eloquent directly, you could look into the [`skip`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) function to do just that:

```
$user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->skip(100)->take(100);
```

However, if you are working with collection, the [`slice`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-slice) function is required.

```
$user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->slice(100)->take(100);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::skip does not exist ?

Comment: I've fixed it using    $user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->slice(100)->take(100);

Comment: I've edited my question accordignly. But i think you should use the Elegant way, since you are returning all the results, and then picking the 100 next one, while you could just return the 100 next one. If you got a billions email, this could be worth checking. @CourtneyWhite

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [forPage](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/f40714bd9120bf9325d23835b75461384831a7c6/Query/Builder.php#L1946).

```
// first 100
$user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->take(100);

// next 200
$user_emails = User::latest()->pluck('email')->forPage(2, 100);
```